# Post AJAX JSON with session id

Tags: nodes, ajax, services, 8, sessions

Using Drupal Services I am able to log in but each time I post a node it posts as anonymous. I get the session id and session name upon login but can´t pass it along with a POST no matter what i try.

I have tried including it in the json string, as a header and within the URL - without any result. I'm testing using the Chrome Postman as REST client.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any help!

```
var session_id = $('#session_id').text();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://www.website.com/active_services/node?sessid='+session_id, 
  data: JSON.stringify(noden),
  headers : {
    "Authorization" : session_id,
    "sessid" : session_id,
    "sessionid" : session_id,
  }, 
  beforeSend: function (req){
    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization",session_id);
    req.setRequestHeader("sessid",session_id);
    req.setRequestHeader("sessionid",session_id);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  },    
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
 }
```

Comment: Are you using any REST client to test this out ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to test my REST calls to server.

When i try http://mysite.com/api/endpoint/users/login.json

with parametes

1. Content-Type - application/json
2. username - A valid username on site
3. password - users password

I get a json looks like this

```
{
    "sessid": "6nRaPdlYfV4mDt0cgUHfGwNmWJZNvUfKM618DYY4unc",
    "session_name": "SESS4356595e5cb4b5df8f18058cfbd8d13a",
    "user": {
        "uid": "144",
```

From that i suspect you should pass `sessid` and `session_name` to get it work.

Try it and let me know whether its working if not we find some other solution which works :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I have always been able to receive the session name and ID without a problem. The problem is that I can't pass them when I'm POSTing a node-create. I test using Chrome Postman as well. 

How should I setup my ajax POST above so the session info gets correctly transferred and I post as a signed in user? @Nikhilm

Comment: Just login to website in other tab :)

Comment: But im not using a browser, I'm creating an iPhone app that connects to the Drupal services API. Any ideas? :) @Nikhilm